# Node Parsing Error: unexpected token when returning

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, mapping

I am trying to return a value to a mapped array, the name of this value is latestDeploymentDate, however, I receive a parsing error, as listed in the title. I am wanting to return the time of the latest deployment my using the `ta.ago` function however, I receive a parsing error because of this, I have thought of creating a separate array with the times in, but cannot seem to get this to work. It needs returning like this because there will be multiple instances of the time, which need to be returned to be outputted.

```
    const express = require('express')();
    const request = require('request');
    const moment = require('moment');
    const ta = require('time-ago')();

    const webApplications = require('./XXX.json');



    express.listen(3000, function() {

      console.log('XXX...');
      express.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.json(webApplications.map((item, latestDeploymentDate) => {
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', true);
          const newrequest = {
            url: `XXX`,
            headers: {
              'X-Api-Key': 'XXX'
            }
          }
          const gitlabRequest = {
            url: `XXX`,
            headers: {
              'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'XXX'
            }
          }
          request(newrequest,(err, resp, body) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(body);
            const latestDeployment = data.deployments[0];
            latestDeploymentDate = new Date(latestDeployment.timestamp);

            //  console.log(latestDeploymentDate, laz1testDeployment);
            // res.json({latestDepoloyment: latestDeployment});
            //  return;

            request(gitlabRequest, (err, resp, body) => {
              const gitlabData = JSON.parse(body);
              const currentTag = latestDeployment.description;
              var currentIndex;

            console.log(`${item.appName}` + ' ');
            console.log(`Last deployed: ${latestDeployment.description}
              on ${moment(latestDeploymentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`);

              gitlabData.find((item, index) => {
                currentIndex = index;
                return item.name == currentTag
              });
              if (currentIndex > 3) {
${ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)}`);
                console.log(`This ${currentIndex} was released ${ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)}`);
                var deployedDate = ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate);
              } else {
${ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)}`);
                var deployedDate = ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate);
                console.log(`This ${currentIndex} was released ${ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)}`);
              }
              //  res.end();
            })
          })
          return {appName: item.appName, ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)};
        }));
      });
    })
```

Comment: can you post the error stack trace?

Comment: /Users/jba71/last-app-web/server-copy-new.js:66
      return {appName: item.appName, ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)};
                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3

Answer (score 1):

Missing json key in return object :

```
return {appName: item.appName, MYKEY: ta.ago(latestDeploymentDate)};
```